How can I Set multiple control values with a single button control in LabView
I have several slider controls and knob controls that generate simulated signal output. Some generate standard 4-20mA signals, some generate different ranges of voltage signals.
I want to create some buttons that are preset scenarios/states of the system, and send set values to the different controls. A table lookup would make the most sense, but I'm ok with sending a simple single value to each control (of course the values would be different depending on the control, I.e. Input Temp vs Output Temp).
What's the easiest way to do this?

You have few options:

Local variables for each control - fastest, easiest to do, just create a local variable and wire it.
Property nodes - slightly slower, but with more capabilities. You can make it so it generates an event when the control or indicator value changes. It also has error IO.
By reference - Similar to property nodes but more generic. You can build an array of control references, each can have a different type and iterate over them in a for loop, for example to initiate them all to their default values.

